# How to find source of power steering fluid leak?

Tags: power-steering, camry, lexus

How do I pinpoint a power steering fluid leak without replacing everything? fluid leaks out completely if filled up. I am not sure if i am skilled enough to do job myself or if its too dangerous. if anyone has experience with this i would greatly appreciate it. Ive been underneath and i think its the idle control valve on pump. It was loose a tad bit but not sure if its supposed to be like that or not.

The vehicle is a 1994 lexus ls400.

Comment: Take your car to an independent mechanic.

Answer (score 3):

There are fluorescent dyes that you can add to oil to detect leaks. [Here is an example](http://www.oreillyauto.com/site/c/detail/INT0/374CS/N1786.oap?ck=Search_N1786_-1_-1&pt=N1786&ppt=C0050) - You can add it to the PS fluid reservoir, run the car a while, and then use a UV light around the engine bay to hopefully find the leak. I am surprised that a high leak rate such as this is not showing evidence on the ground.

Comment: If the OP's driveway looks like mine, there's so much evidence that you can't tell which evidence is which.

Comment: Ha :). However, I imagine that a clean flattened cardboard box or newspaper can serve to show the location of any fresh leaks.